# Accessing SPWorkflowStatus from an SPListItem

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I'm trying to hide/show items based off of their workflow being "Approved" using MOSS 2007.  Logically, SPWorkflowStatus would be a property of SPWorkflow or SPListItem.  But its not, and I'm striking out everywhere.  Any help would be great.  The workflow is not a custom built workflow, just one created with the MOSS UI.

Thanks Mark for the answer.  The values one gets from that column come from the SPWorkFlowStatus enum.

```
WSS
Completed = 5,
ErrorOccurred = 3,
ErrorOccurredRetrying = 7,
FailedOnStart = 1,
FailedOnStartRetrying = 6,
InProgress = 2,
Max = 15,
NotStarted = 0,
StoppedByUser = 4,
ViewQueryOverflow = 8
```

MOSS
Rejected = 17
    Approved = 16
    Canceled = 15

Comment: How is this not a custom workflow if you are writing C# code?

Comment: It's not a custom workflow.  I'm writing code to determine the state of the workflow.  They aren't synonymous.  The workflow itself was created by the MOSS GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally there is a column on the list that has the name of the Workflow which has these values attached.

Comment: Not only that, but the actuall value of the column comes from the SPWorkflowStatus enum.  Thanks Mark.


For WSS
    Completed = 5
    ErrorOccurred = 3
    ErrorOccurredRetrying = 7
    FailedOnStart = 1
    FailedOnStartRetrying = 6
    InProgress = 2
    Max = 15
    NotStarted = 0
    StoppedByUser = 4
    ViewQueryOverflow = 8

For MOSS
    Rejected = 17
    Approved = 16
    Canceled = 15